# Why can't F# compiler infer type in this case?

Tags: f#, type-inference

It seems that the p argument in printPerson function can't be inferred to be Person, but intelisense shows for both of printPerson calls that I'm passing p : Person. Help me understand what I'm doing wrong please?

```
type Person (name:string) = 
        member e.Name = name

type EmployeeNode = 
    | Leader of Person * int * list<EmployeeNode>
    | Employee of Person * int

let printPerson level p = 
    printfn "%s %s" <| String.replicate (level) "#" <| p.Name 

let rec print node  = 
    match node with
    | Employee(p, level) -> printPerson level p
    | Leader(p, level, nodes) -> 
        printPerson level p
        List.iter print nodes
```

Comment: Intellisense type inference is by necessity fuzzier than compile-time type inference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are working with simple immutable data containers in F#, you will find it easier to write idiomatic code, making use of type inference, with [Records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/records) rather than standard .NET classes.

You would change your definition of `Person` as follows:

```
type Person = {Name : string}
```

If you use a record, you do not need to use a type annotation and can keep your code as it is:

```
let printPerson level p = 
    printfn "%s %s" <| String.replicate (level) "#" <| p.Name
```

I would recommend this approach, especially because records give you additional bonuses for free such as automatic structural equality and comparison.

---

If you use a standard .NET class you must provide a type annotation to disambiguate the specific type you are referring to which exposes the `Name` property:

```
type Person (name:string) = 
    member e.Name = name

let printPerson level (p : Person) = 
    printfn "%s %s" <| String.replicate (level) "#" <| p.Name
```

Comment: It's surprising to me that type inference works here, and to be honest I don't like that it does (but I do like advice to prefer records). But note that you need to be careful about record field name conflicts. E.g. it seems that if you also have `type Person2 = {Name: string; Age: int}` F# will infer whichever of them is later for `printPerson` (you can still use annotation to specify). So in a large program adding a record in one file could unexpectedly change type of your functions defined elsewhere.

Comment: @Alexey that's a good point, but wouldn't type inferrence be limited to open modules only though? Still a problem, but less severe

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I'm only surprised how poorly documented this appears to be at the moment as this has always been one of the key advantages of records over standard classes but you are right that caution is needed when re-using the same property names.

Comment: @DevNewb That's right, it is indeed limited to open modules.

Answer (score 6):

Multiple types could have a member `this.Name`, even if they don't in this example, so the compiler doesn't know that you meant `Person`.  Say for example you had

```
type Person (name : string) =
    member this.Name = name

type School (name : string, address : string) =
    member this.Name = name
    member this.Address = address

let printName x = printfn "%s" x.Name       // This is a type error.
```

The compiler can't tell which you meant - `Person` or `School`.  It doesn't matter if you haven't defined another type with a member of the same name, the compiler still won't take the type because things like type extensions can add members onto types after compilation.

Intellisense knows the types you're *trying* to pass when you call the function, but that's not the same as the compiler enforcing type-safety.  In general, any function which accesses class methods or members will need a type annotation for that class.

To fix your example, you just need to change to

```
let printPerson level p =
```

to

```
let printPerson level (p : Person) =
```

Comment: "In general, any function which accesses class methods or members will need a type annotation for that class."
Is there somewhere I can read more about this?

Comment: @DevNewb There's a good write up on "F# for fun and profit", [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-inference/) - particularly the section headed "Not enough information".

Comment: ah, see but here we **can** access the class member Length without annotation:
`["hello"; "world"] |> List.map (fun s -> s.Length)   //ok`
is there any way I could modify my code to do that? I've tried but failed

Comment: @DevNewb Unfortunately not in this case - the example you gave works because the function "definition" (a loose term, since it's a lambda) comes at the same time as the first usage.  Assuming you want `printPerson` to be reusable (and you should, because you use it twice), you must define it before you use it, and that means it needs a type annotation.  It's sadly not that neat, but the best we can do in this situation.

Comment: @DevNewb: More precisely, it works because the type of `s` is inferred from the type of list on the left-hand side of the pipe operator. If you iterate over a list of `Persons` and inline your `printName` function there, you won't need an annotation either.

Answer (score 5):

In `printPerson`, the *only* information about `p` the compiler has is that it has a `Name` member. Since there can be other types than `Person` which have one, it can't infer `p` to be `Person`.

In calls of `printPerson` the type of `p` is determined from the pattern, not from the call.